# Focus location bar in Thunar with keyboard shortcut

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, thunar

Is there a keyboard shortcut for focusing the "location bar" (the field that displays the current directory)? Even the Tab-Key does not stop at this field, so I have to use the mouse. Sometimes, it is faster to just type the path to the location you want to browse instead of navigating. Interestingly, Thunar seems to encourage this, because it even comes with a auto-completion for directory names!

It would be very handy if the focus could be set with a keyboard shortcut (e.g. Ctrl+d, which is used by most web browsers to do so).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> as keyboard shorcut to **"Open location**" in Thunar.

If you have set the view in the thunar's menu as **View > Location Sector > Pathbar Style**.

Then when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> a little window called open location will be open

[image]

But if you set the view as ***View > Location Sector > toolbar Style**.
The focus will be in the location bar.

[image]

Hope this will helpful!

Regards.

Comment: This was extremely helpful. Thank you very much!